# Изменение цвета меню на сайте

Tags: html, css

Есть на сайте меню, как можно поменять цвет только одного элемента, "инвестиции в компанию". как можно поменять цвет данной строчки?
сайт: https://gls-trade.ru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если этот пункт меню всегда будет последним, то можно с помощью псевдокласса `last-of-type`:

```css
#page-menu nav li:last-of-type a {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-menu" class="no-sticky ">

    <div id="page-menu-wrap">

        <div class="container clearfix">

            <nav class="with-arrows">
                <ul id="menu-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e" class=""><li id="menu-item-79" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-79"><a href="https://gls-trade.ru/?page_id=92">О компании</a> </li>
<li id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-82"><a href="#products">Товары</a> </li>
<li id="menu-item-81" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-81"><a href="https://gls-trade.ru/?page_id=57">Отзывы</a> </li>
<li id="menu-item-83" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-83"><a href="#adres">Контакты</a> </li>
<li id="menu-item-126" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-126"><a href="https://gls-trade.ru/?page_id=124">Инвестиции в компанию</a> </li>
</ul>           </nav>

            <div id="page-submenu-trigger"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: я же ведь добавляю первый код только?

Comment: @MAB, ну да, css

Comment: спасибо большое, все работает